# not able to style a ul inside a nav tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a nav menu for my website and have been using http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/
as a guide. It has worked fine but as soon as I try to add ( id="coolMenu" ) to the nav tag it stops working.

I took it away from the ul tag and added it to the nav tag and it no longer works. It does not display anything at all. What am in doing wrong?

Thanks.

html code below:

```
<nav id="coolMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mauricii</a></li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#">Periher</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="#">Hellenico</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Genere</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Indulgentia</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Tyrio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quicumque</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

css below:

```
/* Structure
------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#coolMenu {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu > li {
    float: left;
}
#coolMenu li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#coolMenu li:hover ul.noJS {
    display: block; 
}


/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #2f8be8;
}
#coolMenu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#coolMenu > li:hover > a {
    background: #f09d28;
    color: #000;
}


/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu ul {
    background: #f09d28;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    color: #000;
}
#coolMenu ul li:hover a {
    background: #ffc97c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Since you put the id on the `nav` element, the main `ul` is set to `display: none`, instead of the submenu `ul`s. If you want to have the id on `nav`, you will have to change all the css selectors to reflect that.

Or, if you want to target the `nav` element, why not just give it a new id and leave the rest as is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do want to have the id on nav so I added nav in the css. ie. #coolMenu nav ul to everything but it is not working as indended. It changed from a horizintal menu to a vertical one and all the colours changed etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way you target it now, the selector will look for a nav element _inside_ the element with id #coolMenu. In the original CSS you gave, replace every `#coolMenu` with `#coolMenu ul`, or `nav#coolMenu ul` to clarify the id belongs to the nav. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
<nav id="coolMenu">
<ul>
```

The ID tag is supposed to be attached to the unordered list, it should be

```
<nav>
<ul id="coolMenu">
```

take a look here at your code with the edit: http://jsfiddle.net/UMTGR/1/

Comment: And the OP already stated that in his question:  _"I took it away from the `ul` tag and added it to the `nav` tag and it no longer works."_  ~ Explain why?